# Use typescript generic to connect props to state in React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there a way for me to make the state type depend on the prop type passed in?

```
type FooProps = {
  allItems: any[]
}
type FooState = {
  items: any[]
}
export default class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps, FooState> {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried it?

```
interface FooProps<T> {
    allItems: T[]
}

interface FooState<T> {
    items: T[]
}

export default class Foo<T> extends React.Component<FooProps<T>, FooState<T>> {}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Avallon, but why is there a `U`?

Comment: Sorry @stackjlei, I didn't realize it was the same type of data for the props and the state. I thought they were different types. In that case, it really is just remove U. I fixed my answer. Hope it helps.